# Accessing the Response object from my WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

In my WCF service class which is in the same project as my WebSite I inherit from System.Web.UI.Page so that I have access to the Page.Response object but when I use it I get the error:
"Response is not available in this context."

I want to save to a file the results passes in to my WCF service like so:

```
            public void SendList(List<ListType> listTypes)
            {        
                Response.Clear(); 
                Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filew.csv");
  //etc
            }
```

How can I do this if I can't access the Response object?

Answer (score 1):

WCF should not be treated as simply http - i.e. it won't normally make sense to do what you have suggested above. You can do something comparable by writing a "message inspector" that adds a WCF header. A WCF service is not a `Page`, and can't be treated as one.

For the *request*, there is as as [ASP.NET compatibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx) flag that can be enabled (providing access to [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)), but the general advice is: don't.

So: what is it you are actually trying to do? What is your objective here?

Comment: Hi Marc, any advice on my other comment below?